# How do I add methods to an existing Python submodule with pybind11?

Tags: python, pybind11

I have a Python module named 'my_module' which contains the file '_internal.py'. From Python I can access the methods of _internal.py as follows:

```
import my_module
my_module._internal.some_method()
```

I'd like to use pybind11 to add some bindings to _internal but can't figure out how to do it. I tried the following:

```
auto m_internal = pybind11::module::import("my_module._internal");
m_internal.def("_test_func", test_func, "Test function.");
```

There were no errors or exceptions, but _test_func wasn't present in _internal at runtime.

Is it even possible to do this?